# Add new filed and clone in bootstrap 3 modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using some append new data in form, that does not exists

**HTML**

Phone number :

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var phone_number_form_index=0;
    $("#add_phone_number").click(function(){
        phone_number_form_index++;
        $(this).parent().before($("#phone_number_form").clone().attr("id","phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index));
        $("#phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index).css("display","inline");
        $("#phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index + " :input").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") + phone_number_form_index);
            $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id") + phone_number_form_index);
            });
        $("#remove_phone_number" + phone_number_form_index).click(function(){
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    }); 
});
```

And here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wc28f/3/

I am trying to add to boostrap 3 modal, but i have no luck, here is that same code in bootstrap 3 modal

http://www.bootply.com/J9cv7EZv6K

Does can be extended this exmaple like select, but what i need post array of that select values

http://www.bootply.com/S9WGrK0WhL

Here is my example, what i need is to

- phone_number1 **becomes** phone_number[1],
- and qty1 to **becomes** qty[1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Working demo](http://www.bootply.com/JYgeWsuZSx)

I have removed line and it worked

```
$("#phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index).css("display","inline");
```

Used this:

```
$("#phone_number_form" + phone_number_form_index).removeClass("hidden");
```

You want `phone_number[1]` try this:

```
$(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") +"["+ phone_number_form_index+"]");
```

[Updated DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/z97bLi9ql7)

Comment: Can this be more fixed that  $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") + phone_number_form_index);  Becomes like phone_number[1] that all other elements can be in array, when submitting to know that inputs are in array